# AJAX implemented with zend framework on ONBLUR Property of input box

Tags: zend-framework

I am new in Zend framework. I want to implement AJAX with zend framework. I want to call a ajax on **onblur** property of a input box to dispaly a message.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/about : "Don't ask about Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"

Answer (score 0):

In form file you can add add

```
->setAttrib('onblur',"checkEmailExited(this.value);")
```

for email validation at text box.

In view file or in Javascript you can call custom function like

```
<script lanaguage="javascript">

   function checkEmailExited(email){

  JQObj.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'index','action'=>'checkemail','module'=>'ajax'))?>",      
       data: "email="+email, 
       success: function(data){


       if(data == 1){

        var massage = "That email address is unavailable <span class='hint-pointer'> </span>";
        JQObj("#email_m").css({'display':'block','color':'red'});
       JQObj("#email_m").html(massage);
       return false;
       }else{

       }

      }
     }); 

}

</script>
```

**Controller file**

public function checkemailAction(){

```
$this->getHelper('layout')->disableLayout();
$this->getHelper('viewRenderer')->setNoRender();

$objRequest = $this->getRequest();
$objModelUser = new Models_User();

$emailAddress= $this->_getParam('email');

$emailFlag =  $objModelUser->checkEmailExisted($emailAddress,""); 
echo $emailFlag; exit;
```

}

let me know if i can help you more

Comment: thank you, can you tell me ajax code and i want to know how i pass the controller name and value from the checkEmailExited.

Comment: @Delta pls see my updated answer it will defiantly help you. i would be appreciate if your issue will resolve please accept my answer..

Comment: pls see my updated answer and it would be better if you make function for model with your way :)